# Create Dynamic Array with fixed number of columns

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need to create a two dimensional table that I know its number of columns but I don't know the number of rows. The rows will be generated through the code and added to the table.
My question is, which data structure in java do you think it would be the best for these features?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a class with a field for each of your columns. For example, here is a `Person` class.

```
public final class Person {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String firstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String lastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int age() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Then you can create an `ArrayList<Person>`. The number of rows will be increased as needed.

For example

```
List<Person> table = new ArrayList<>();
table.add(new Person("John", "Smith", 52);
table.add(new Person("Sarah", "Collins", 26);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- Create a domain class and put its instances into `ArrayList`, as @pbabcdefp suggested
- Put raw arrays into `ArrayList`:

  ```
  List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
  list.add(new int[] {4, 5, 6});
  ```
- Use some special datastructure, like [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) from [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

  ```
  Table<Integer, String, Object> table = HashBasedTable.create();
  // row 1
  table.put(1, "Name", "John");
  table.put(1, "Age", 22);
  // row 2
  table.put(2, "Name", "Mike");
  table.put(2, "Age", 33);
  ```